# How much is MathOverflow exposed to recent events on StackExchange?

Tags: discussion, policy, stackexchange

[Long-time 10k+ MO user here, asking this question anonymously for reasons that should be obvious. 
**Added Oct 16: My access to this account will self-destruct in 3, 2, 1 ....** (sorry, won't be able to accept an official answer. For what it's worth, I strongly support Tim Campion's suggestion.)]

> This question is **not** meant to be a place to discuss the pros and cons of the dumpster fire on meta.SE, or the underlying issues that started it. Go there if you want to get depressed. Also, I think that **only moderators are in a position to answer this question.**

The short background is that StackExchange Inc. 1) is trying to implement a new Code of Conduct (CoC), and it's proving difficult, and 2) has retroactively relicensed *all* existing content, questioned by many as being of dubious legality. These are separate issues, but have both contributed to a wide feeling (expressed through community voting and extensive commenting) that SE Inc. is making a mess of things, one way or another.

Since MathOverflow uses the SE platform, but is actually [a different organisation](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/969/who-owns-mathoverflow) it is not clear what exposure (in the sense of risk) MO has to the recent controversies. Are our moderators bound by the same agreement as the SE network moderators? Will the CoC apply here, when it is finally sorted out? Were contributions to MO retroactively relicensed (making [this question](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/950/who-owns-my-mathoverflow-posts) outdated)?

Again, the intent of this question is not the *content* of the CoC or the relicensing issue, but to get in writing the facts of where MO stands in relation to these from a contractual/legal/etc way.

---

**Edit** (To clarify some things) I asked this question in a slightly vague way, partly because I didn't want to pre-empt any position or bring up debates here. But I've read a bit more, and Johannes pointed out some relevant facts in an answer. So here are some more focussed questions. Again, this is **not to debate the merit or otherwise of the below points**, I'm looking for official answers from mods or MO owners/board members on policy about changes that StackExchange Inc makes.

- StackExchange relicensed all contributions users had made to their websites (from CC-By-SA 3.0 to CC-By-SA 4.0, which change the CC people say can't be made without permission), but this has also relicensed all MathOverflow content too. Is this compatible with [the agreement between the MathOverflow corporation and StackExchange Inc](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-Rx93qiEH3t9wAwsyvuVzjawF62X6OgI/view)?
- I presume that there is very little objection to the principles of the new Code of Conduct (CoC), and find it nigh-impossible to forsee any circumstances in which MathOverflow as an organisation would object to the now in-position wording, and adopting the CoC as official here (were it a choice). However, the official FAQ on the CoC, which has given rise to concerns among many StackExchange users, is getting rather distant from any document that I can see referred to under the legal agreement between MathOverflow and StackExchange Inc. The CoC is linked to from MathOverflow pages, and so is, it seems, in effect and binding. I haven't seen, after some cursory clicking about, explicit links from MathOverflow to the contentious FAQ. Does this latter nonetheless carry force on MathOverflow to the extent it does on the StackExchange network? Will all future policy changes in the same manner also immediately and automatically apply on MathOverflow? (Added: I note that this type of question was raised [nearly six years ago](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/969/who-owns-mathoverflow#comment4931_970), to which it seems the official answer was, to paraphrase, MathOverflow has an informal understanding with StackExchange Inc that SE Inc employees shouldn't interfere with our moderation as we can choose to leave the network. However, this seems to me to be a bit like [the nuclear deterrent](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JKbDKsNsjac)...)

Perhaps all of this is moot. But I hope MathOverflow is not hit with the same <s>ugly stick</s> terrible optics that StackExchange Inc has encountered in trying to create an environment that once was expressed through 'be nice'.

Update: Yesterday a [new FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/336364/what-does-the-code-of-conduct-say-about-pronouns) regarding the pronoun discussion has been released. This new FAQ is based on previous input from the community and it seems that the acceptance of these new rules is (so far) much higher.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that so long as MO stays on the platform we're subject to the same CoC as everyone else.  We could of course try to take our ball and go home.  But although my heart breaks for Monica (who's an old friend from another site, who I think very highly of, and who was really terribly treated), as far as I can tell there's nothing actually bad in the CoC, so I can't imagine leaving being seriously considered.

Comment: @NoahSnyder I still don't fully understand what's going on even after several hours of reading over the last two days. Most of the uproar that isn't tied to Monica's firing but to the new CoC itself seems to come from the FAQ post which reads very different than the CoC itself. It is easy to read the new code charitable and as an expansion of the general "don't be a dick" theme of the CoC. It is much harder to read the FAQ in this way. Especially the questions about what is considered a violation and how violations will be enforced are causing worries.

Comment: The FAQ is very weirdly written at points and I can see why you might be concerned.  But I'd be really surprised if the board is considering leaving preemptively before seeing if it ends up being frequently applied unreasonably (and not just the unobjectionable "conspicuously avoiding one person's pronouns while using other people's pronouns makes you a jerk" which seems to be the corner case leading to the weird writing).

Comment: And "considering leaving" is maybe too strong. How about "Right now, I'm glad that the option is there if we need it" ?

Comment: I certainly agree with that.

Comment: @user76284 the links you gave were deleted. What did they say?

Comment: I think the meta.SE post about pronouns with the best ratio of light to heat is [this one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/335234/) which has a more understandable version of what the FAQ is hopefully trying to say and an insightful answer with a somewhat different viewpoint raising a few objections.  I think it's really unfortunate that SE rolled this out in a way that would maximize distrust of them (since Monica is widely beloved), not least because it's harmful for SE's trans and non-binary users that their reasonable requests are now associated with SE's unreasonable behavior.

Comment: @Noah Snyder: Well, to my understanding Monica is a victim of *some* LGBTQ people. She used to write in a gender-neutral way (as most of us do on MO) and was blamed by this group for not using prefered pronouns.

Comment: @tj_  Do you have any evidence to back that up?  As far as public information goes it appears that the main people involved in that decision are cis straight people.

Comment: To make things clear for casual readers, the link in @NoahSnyder's comment does *not* discuss the official FAQ. Rather, it proposes a *replacement* for the FAQ. It is basically irrelevant, as the company has made it clear over the course of the last year or two that they have zero interest in taking suggestions from the community into account, they just want everybody to shut up and do what they are told.

Comment: Also, at this point it’s clear that the company does not care one iota about members of the LGBTQ+ community, or of any of their other users for that matter. Users of the free service are not customers, but a product; SE treats them (that is, us) as an expendable commodity it owns. The only point of the CoC update is that they can show it to their investors and real customers (advertisers, etc.): “here, look, we care about inclusiveness and diversity”. The actual effects of the change mean nothing to them.

Comment: Let me also note that I will keep this Incognito browser window open as long as I can, to keep this burner account cookie around. But I cannot guarantee I can wait indefinitely for a response, so apologise if this gets an official answer and this account is not longer available to me to accept said answer.

Comment: For what it's worth, I'm a man and tick all the privilege boxes. Please take this question in good faith; I presumed it would come up at some point, and wanted to raise it in a dispassionate way so an official answer can be pointed to if needed in future. I'm losing the will to think about the StackExchange Inc v MathOverflow issue, so it might be best if this sinks into obscurity.

Comment: I think the short answer is that at the other forums there is community discontent and belief they have loss of power over their participation, and that there is some fight for control.  Andrew Stacey had a remark which I interpret as "if everyone realized that there was room for mistakes and forgiveness, then everyone could contribute to the common goals of the forum".  I am hoping to help steer this forum toward that. Gerhard "Get Along To Get Along" Paseman, 2019.10.13.

Comment: @Gerhard +1, I think that sums up the situation well.

Comment: Concerning the licensing issue, it might be a good idea if representatives of the MathOverflow corporation in their official capacity ask SE for explanation what is the legal basis for this unilateral retroactive licence change. They staunchly refuse to say anything to users, but they just might treat a request from the MO corp. more seriously.

Comment: @Emil yes, I agree, and focussing just on MO content will highlight the tricky situation better.

Comment: Sorry, I try to read all the discussion on meta-SE, but it soon became too complicated and Kafkian for me. Just a question: may I still use expressions like ''the OP'' in a MO-thread, or this is going to offend someone?

Comment: @FrancescoPolizzi There is some discussion of “the OP” in the FAQ thread, but it seems inconclusive. The only thing that’s clear is that if a CM determines it might offend someone, the punishment will be swift and hard.

Comment: That is, the official “rule” is apparently that if you know someone’s pronouns, and call them “the OP”, it’s ok if this is something you would do anyway, but it is a punishable violation of the CoC if you’ve done it in order to avoid using the pronouns. Since SE failed to issue moderators with mind-reading technology, it’s anyone’s guess how they are supposed to judge your *intent*.

Comment: Am I particularly susceptible, or this at the very least seems irrational, and at worst borders on lunatic?

Comment: My opinion is that requiring the use of requested pronouns and punishing people for using a completely innocent and neutral form as "the OP" is coercing speech.

Comment: You judge intent in this case the same way that you judge it in other cases: by examining the visible evidence.  If somebody's posting history makes it clear that they always say "the OP", then the intent in using it now is probably not to avoid pronouns.  But if their posting history makes it clear that they regularly use pronouns and have never before said "the OP", then the intent behind its use now is much more questionable.  _Mens rea_ goes back at least to the 13th century (says Wikipedia) and has never required mind-reading, just examination of the available evidence.

Comment: (But my previous comment does not mean that I endorse scrutinizing everybody's language for offences to judge this way.  Assuming good faith means that if somebody decides to stop using pronouns to avoid the risk of misusing them (and consequently misgendering people), then this should be seen as a desire to do good and be accepted.  And on the topic of judging intent, a stated intention should usually be trusted.  In my mind, a better framing would be one of discrimination: if you treat cis and trans people differently when it comes to pronoun usage, then that really starts to be insulting.)

Comment: So you are saying that if someone decides one day to use an expression completely innocent like "the OP" for the first time in his life, we should make a trial and see *how* and *why* he decided to do this? Are you serious? I cannot believe that we could arrive at this point.

Comment: For the sake of some misinterpreted "inclusiveness", we are making people afraid to speak and we are coercing their language, expecting to judge their *intent*. We are using the expression *mens rea* when talking about "the OP"! We suddendly are in "1984", or what?

Comment: The **only** way "the OP" can be insulting is if the OP (him/her/them)self(ves)  explicitly ask(s) to be called by using the pronoun, and one insists saying "the OP". This would be clearly rude, and must be avoided. Otherwise, we cannot punish someone just because a neutral expression *might* offend someone *for some unknown reasons*.

Comment: I just discovered "ze", "zir" in these threads. So far, when I was in doubt I always used either "they" or "the OP", and I was sure it was ok.

Comment: I find this question baffling for several reasons. I don't understand why any of this is a big deal, nor do I understand why the OP feels the need to post "anonymously for reasons that should be obvious." The latter sounds like weird paranoia or an attempt to create an air of spy drama. I don't see any link in the question to whatever material about pronouns seems to be generating Oh My God reactions in a few people. The question is written as if this were some sort of existential threat to MO, which seems extremely silly.

Comment: About the "anonymously for reasons that should be obvious", I agree. Regarding the pronouns, the big discussion is here:

https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/334900/official-faq-on-gender-pronouns-and-code-of-conduct-changes?cb=1

There is no "existential threat", but many people are evidently upset.

Comment: @tj_ "Why should a minority of users have the right to dictate other users which words they have to use?" So I guess if I want to call black people the n-word I should have the right to? What right does a minority have to dictate which words I use? (In case this is not clear, this is reductio ad absurdum. Any reasonable person would agree that calling black people the n-word is bad. Claiming that minorities don't have the right to tell you what you can/can't call them is absurd.)

Comment: @Najib Idrissi: My comment is concerned with neopronouns.

Comment: @tj_ It's rather sad that a mathematician can't understand analogies.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi It’s one thing to demand that users *shouldn’t* use certain words such as the offensive name you are talking about, and it’s a completely different thing to demand that users *must* use certain words (some of which are not even actual English words in the first place). It’s called compelled speach.

Comment: Having said that, SE now scrapped the original CoC FAQ and replaced it with a much better one, taking the most important complaints of the community into account, see https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/336364 and https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/336366 . There is some hope the company finally started to communicate with its users again. However, the situation of Monica (that involved highly unethical behaviour on the part of SE) as well as other issues such as illegal relicensing remain unresolved as yet.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek Funnily enough, my comment pointing out that in real life, people who call other people by names they don't like are considered as assholes was deleted. Is this *gasp* compelled speech?! (cue scary X-Files music theme)

Comment: @NajibIdrissi What does that have to do with the difference between negative and positive commands?

Comment: @NajibIdrissi Based on your offensive comment that I’ve actually seen before it was deleted, I suspect you still don’t understand the issue. Consider the following: (1) “Don’t call me n**** or asshole.” (2) “Whenever you speak about me, you must call me ‘btxp’. You can’t just call me by name, by a description such as ‘the OP’, by a neutral pronoun, or in any other way. If you speak about me, even indirectly, in a sentence that does not include ‘btxp’, it is an offence.” For me (unlike you, it seems) , (1) is a prefectly reasonable request that should be honoured in any civil conversation. ...

Comment: ... In contrast, (2) is an absurd unreasonable demand. (2) is compelled speech. (2) was included in the draft CoC update whose discussion led to Monica’s dismissal, (2) was included in the original FAQ following the CoC update, (2) is what tj_ and me were talking about.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek I am not sure how it is offensive to say that in real life, when you call someone by a name they don't like, then you are considered to be an asshole. Perhaps it is not clear, and my lack of English skills are showing, but "you" is a general you, not "you, Emil Jeřábek". If A asked B to refer to A as "she" or "ze" and B said "he" when speaking to someone else, then yes, B would be an asshole. I am not making any claims about you specifically and if you are choosing to see it this way, then it is your own issue.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek "What does that have to do with the difference between negative and positive commands?" If you had actually read my deleted comment, then you would know what I think about this. You *shouldn't* call people names they don't like. If you do, you will face consequences. The CoC outlined these consequences. If you interpret it as the fact that you *mustn't* call people names they don't like because you don't want to face these consequences, then you are responsible for this interpretation. What happens when someone only likes certain names is left as an exercise to the reader.

Comment: You keep setting up straw men. There is no issue whatsoever with the fact that you *mustn’t* call people using certain words. (Whether you write “shouldn’t” or “mustn’t” has no bearing on the issue.) The issue is that they demand that you *must* call them using certain words.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek "What happens when someone only likes certain names is left as an exercise to the reader."

Comment: @NajibIdrissi Continuing your example, it’s not that A asked B to refer to A as “she” and B said “he”. Assume B actually said “In the original post, A wrote that ....”. According to the original FAQ, *this is already a violation of the CoC*.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek When you talk about strawmen... In the original CoC, this would be a violation only if you wouldn't ordinarily write the sentence like this and only do it to discriminate A. Since pretty much everyone writes sentences like this (referring to people by their name), nobody would have been in violation of the CoC by writing this sentence. You are grasping at straws.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek When people avoid using pronouns because they disagree with the chosen pronouns of some people, they end up formulating rather awkward sentences where the lack of pronouns is very clear and that way it becomes a way to show your disagreement with the chosen pronoun while not violating the old CoC. This is what they wanted to stop with the new CoC.

Comment: @Tobias Kildetoft: Can you give an example for a sentence that is rather awkwardly formulated because someone avoided using pronouns?

Comment: @tj: well, if there are three people, asking to be called by *he, she* and *ze*, respectively, and one writes something like "he did such and such, she did such and such and *that person* did such and such", this would be extremely rude, in my opinion.

Comment: @tj_ As Francesco mentions, there are the very clear examples. But Francesco could also have given other examples (I am sure said person is aware of these, so this is not meant to single Francesco out or in any way disregard what the person in question said). Yes, this was obviously a very contrived example, but turning it into something that sounds natural without pronouns is still nontrivial.

Comment: @Francesco Polizzi: On MO/SE one could simply use "@A did such and such, @B  did such and such and @C  did such and such". When addressing a person (on MO/SE) for the first time, it's usual to use the username or OP, anyway, and not pronouns.

Comment: Note that the "extremely disappointed" letter to Stack Exchange was signed by Todd Trimble (one of our moderators), as well as Asaf Karagila and Joonas Ilmavarta (active participants here, moderators on other StackExchange sites): https://dearstackexchange.com/

Answer (score 85):

I think that given the sort of turmoil experienced of late at Stack Exchange, it might be wise for us here at MO to take certain measures to reinforce our status as an entity independent from Stack Exchange. I'm no legal expert, but I think our [migration agreement](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-Rx93qiEH3t9wAwsyvuVzjawF62X6OgI/view) is rather vague on many points concerning exactly what our status is. And if we establish too much precedent of deferring to Stack Exchange, that could come back to bite us down the road. For example, we might contemplate

- Writing our own Code of Conduct. It could even be verbatim the same as Stack Exchange's, but it would be ours to interpret as we see fit.
- Agreeing on our own licensing convention. That might mean we use the same license as Stack Exchange uses, but it would be our decision.
- Negotiating some written agreement with Stack Exchange over when they can and cannot unilaterally "fire" one of our moderators.

I don't know what kind of standing we have to do any of these things, but I think steps like this might be worth discussing.

Comment: Good idea, IMHO. Here's a virtual +1 as this account can't upvote.

Comment: It has been > 2 years. Where are the steps that MO has taken with respect to these three points you stated?

Comment: @user21820 I'll point out that at the time I wrote this answer, I was not a moderator, so this answer shouldn't be taken as "official MO policy". As far as I'm aware, not much has been done along these lines, so thanks for the nudge.

Comment: Oh oops I didn't realize your moderatorship started later! Thanks for responding, and I would be glad to see an update on this in the future. =)

Answer (score 10):

The answer to

> Will the CoC apply here, when it is finally sorted out?

seems to be "there is no 'will' and 'finally'". The [blog entry](https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/10/10/iterating-on-inclusion/) posted on october 10th shows (some?) of the controversial changes to the CoC. The two changes mentioned in the blog post are *already* part of [MO's CoC](https://mathoverflow.net/help/conduct). I cannot say whether those lines were there before a couple of days ago, but they are there now.

Comment: I just saw the new code of conduct at the linked page. A [version of that page from 15 March 2019](https://web.archive.org/web/20190315185539/https://mathoverflow.net/conduct) is different to what it is now.

Comment: Note that the license issue, which was also mentioned by OP, is a lot less clear. SE claims that all the site content [has already been effectively relicensed to CC 4.0](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/333089/stack-exchange-and-stack-overflow-have-moved-to-cc-by-sa-4-0), including the posts here on MO, but many users claim that they [do not have the right](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/333094/243091) to relicense all existing content without the authors' consent.

Answer (score 10):

There are very few MathOverflow posts in which anyone might feel a need to use a third person pronoun.  If such a situation arose, it is most likely that the writer would naturally use a pronoun that everyone involved was happy with.  In the unlikely event that a pronoun was used and someone was unhappy with it, by far the most likely scenario is that the question would be resolved amicably with an apology freely offered and graciously accepted.  So my estimate of our "exposure to recent events" is zero.

Comment: One would hope amicable solutions can be speedily arrived at in all cases. But this is not really an answer to the question, which is more after a more-or-less official answer about the relationship between SE Inc and MathOverflow, and if and how changes the former makes on the SE platform do or don't apply automatically to MO, given MO's special status.

Comment: "it is most likely that the writer would naturally use a pronoun that everyone involved was happy with" - The CoC is not about being happy, it's about inclusiveness. For example the usage of "she/he" in https://mathoverflow.net/questions/92750/polynomials-for-addition-in-the-witt-vectors/93047#93047 excludes trans persons. To my understanding, in the specific case of the linked question, under the new CoC, one needs to use singular they in place of "she/he".

Comment: The usage of she/he in that question is clearly meant to be inclusive... Also, it doesn't necessarily exclude transgender people, since many of those identify with a specific gender... It could be interpreted as excluding non-binary people, if one is so inclined, but perhaps we could salvage this with a topological interpretation? she---he is a continuum, not necessarily one-dimensional, in a larger dimensional manifold (humanity) that cannot be split continuously.

Comment: @FrankaWaaldijk Interesting. We should write it as [she,he], then?

Comment: I’ll answer myself: no, this would imply she${}\le{}$he.

Comment: This analysis is reasonable under the assumption that no one provokes a conflict intentionally (e.g., by changing their pronouns and asking for retroactive changes in existing posts, or declaring their pronouns in an ambiguous way, or otherwise fishing for reasons to be outraged). Unfortunately, this is far from guaranteed on an open forum. (This kind of behavior has happened on the political scene in Canada, for example: google Jessica/Jonathan Yaniv.) The question then becomes whether administration will take the side of the provocateur or that of the community.

Comment: I don't agree that there are very few MO posts in which one might want to use a third person pronoun. Looking through my own previous answers, I almost immediately found something of the form "When Kunen proved..., his result was hailed as..." I can easily imagine saying, "In so-and-so's MO answer to a related question, she invokes such-and-such a theorem." It's true that sometimes these can be rewritten to avoid using a third-person pronoun, but my understanding is that choosing a different phrasing from what you would normally use, solely to avoid a pronoun, is a potential CoC violation.

Comment: @Frank'a Waaldijk: I think that in my example above (under the new CoC) Q6 of the official FAQ (https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/334900/official-faq-on-gender-pronouns-and-code-of-conduct-changes) applies: Q6: What should I do if I don't know someone's pronouns? A: When in doubt, use gender-neutral language or refer to the user by name. -- In the example, the pronoun (she/he) is used in the question and doesn't address a particular user. Hence, no pronoun is known and by Q6 gender-neutral language should be used.

Comment: Neither the "controversy" nor the amendment to the CoC are due to such incidents actually occuring in reality; that's not what it's about. This is a power play, and MO *will* be affected by it.

Comment: The CoC amendments are certainly about real incidents, mostly on sites like The Workplace, Interpersonal Skills, Mi Yodeya etc where there is obvious scope for such incidents to happen.  You have offered no argument at all for why MathOverflow will be affected.

Comment: @NeilStrickland "Certainly"? Did you ever come across such incidents in real life? I didn't. My reason to belief that MO will not be unaffected---despite the apolitical and asexual nature of mathematics---is that I see this as yet another example of an all-to familiar script that has crippled other communities in the past (e.g. atheists, linux kernel devs). The first step is always the introduction of a "code of conduct", written in a way that turns perceived victimhood into a currency yielding the power to silence and deplatform others.

Comment: @NicolasSchmidt I wasn't aware that there was a worldwide code of conduct for atheists. Seems kind of paradoxical. In any case nobody notified me.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi There isn't, nor did I claim there was. Look up "New Atheism" and "Atheism+" for context.

Comment: @NicolasSchmidt I have heard no one disagree that the LKML had a lot of open abuse of a kind that has never been tolerated by community or moderators on MO.  They introduced a CoC, there was a brief burst of drama about it, then everything quickly calmed down.  The loudest complaints were about Linus Torvalds; he stepped away from the project for six weeks, but was hardly silenced or deplatformed.  A look at https://lwn.net/Articles/798505/ does not support the claim that the Linux kernel community was crippled.

Answer (score 5):

It is more likely a question for StackExchange Community Managers than for moderators.  I believe the moderators can provide an interesting but non definitive perspective.  If the comment linked in your edit does not suffice as an answer, I cannot imagine more satisfaction coming from the MathOverflow moderators.  I think (read in my opinion and not StackExchanges) that the less complaints this forum generates, the more the community will be left to manage itself.

Toward the notion of moderating ourselves, I am finding recent instances where the community participating in MathOverflow is not being inclusive. Of course we do not intend to expand the scope to answering standard questions in high school courses (or pick your other line in the sand), but there are other areas where I believe we as community fall short. (For some history, pursue some discussions on tea.MathOverflow, the old meta forum.) Again in my opinion, we the community need to adapt our behaviour toward a model that will support a future audience, not just the present one.

The topic of MathOverflow's current situation is grave enough to me to omit a thought-provoking signature.

Comment: Yes, MO has had (witness blog posts from Izabella Laba, for instance) and I assume still has issues with being welcoming to [congressive mathematicians](http://digitaleditions.walsworthprintgroup.com/publication/?i=566588&article_id=3302575&view=articleBrowser&ver=html5#{%22issue_id%22:566588,%22view%22:%22articleBrowser%22,%22article_id%22:%223302575%22}), let alone people from marginalised backgrounds.

Comment: There is nontrivial overlap between mods and MO board members as far as I can tell, so I would expect them to use that hat. But, I'm feeling increasingly like I maybe should have let this whole issue lie until if and when it becomes more pressing.

Comment: Regarding the discussions over at StackExchange, I think the MathOverflow community has avoided a lot of the angst, even if they are not immune from the underlying issues. There are issues to confront however, and I think your question provides an oblique but effective introduction to these.  Gerhard "Hopefully Good Talk Will Result" Paseman, 2019.10.13.

Comment: The link to congressive mathematicians in the first comment is very worthwhile, imnsho. Thanx!