# Is there a software solution if we do cut the cord from SE?

Tags: discussion, stackexchange, mathoverflow-inc, data-dump, export

There has been some recent concerns about MathOverflow's relationship with StackExchange: see

- [What is MathOverflow's "agreement" with Stack Exchange?](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/4429/what-is-mathoverflows-agreement-with-stack-exchange)
- [How much is MathOverflow exposed to recent events on StackExchange?](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/4368/how-much-is-mathoverflow-exposed-to-recent-events-on-stackexchange)

**Suppose MO were to decide to sever the relationship** (not that I am advocating it at the present), how far away are we from having a replacement?

Finding hosting and DNS service will cost some money, but is relatively benign as problems go. But what about the backend software? Our agreement (a copy is posted [here](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/a/4430/3948)) states in Section 7 that

> Subject to Section 8, should MathOverflow wish to migrate its data outside of the Stack Exchange network, Stack Exchange shall, within thirty (30) days of receipt of a written request from MathOverflow, provide MathOverflow with a complete and current database that contains all the data necessary to recreate MathOverflow on MathOverflow's own servers and software. Following such transfer, StackExchange will cease all use of the MathOverflow database.

Do we know what said database would look like? Is there already software compatible with serving based on that database, or is that something that will require development?

Comment: I would expect the database to be in a form similar to the existing periodic data dumps at https://archive.org/details/stackexchange (not that I have any idea what those looks like inside). Concerning software, see https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2267 . Importing the Stack Exchange data dumps can’t be that difficult, as witnessed by https://writing.codidact.com (which, however, apparently runs on some sort of temporary software).

Comment: [PhysicsOverflow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PhysicsOverflow) has a setup that's reasonably close to MO. It runs on the [Question2Answer](https://www.question2answer.org/) software. It was in part set up a kind of exodus from physics.stackexchange

Comment: Maybe it's fixable with better CSS, but I find PhysicsOverflow's design to be incredibly ugly.

Comment: Codidact was born of a previous mass exodus from SE and has some experience with migrating data from SE to their software platform, QPixel.

Answer (score 14):

Converted from [a comment](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/4431/is-there-a-software-solution-if-we-do-cut-the-cord-from-se/5671#comment28672_4431):

[Codidact](https://codidact.org/) was born of a previous mass exodus from SE and has some experience with migrating data from SE to their software platform, [QPixel](https://github.com/codidact/qpixel).

Comment: If this turns out to be something that needs to be a real option, we should be mindful that there is already a [mathematics community](https://math.codidact.com/) on Codidact. I haven't seen enough it yet to say anything informative

Comment: @DavidRoberts: That community appears to be similar to Math Stack Exchange, which means that it should not be a problem.

Comment: @DavidRoberts, (1) as Moishe Kohan says, it's more a competitor to MSE than to MO; (2) the software platform can in principle be used independently of the network, and I believe there are existing instances of QPixel being used separately from Codidact.

Comment: Hi. I'm a member of the Codidact team. We're happy to discuss options with you if y'all want, either joining our hosted network or setting up your own like [these folks](https://meta.codidact.com/posts/286827) did. I wouldn't want to use SE's platform for that, but you can post on our Meta, ping us in [Discord](https://discord.gg/WZ7aTst), or email us (info at codidact dot org).

Comment: @Monica thanks for that.

Answer (score 5):

Converted from [a comment](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/4431/is-there-a-software-solution-if-we-do-cut-the-cord-from-se#comment21496_4431):

I would expect the database to be in a form similar to the existing periodic data dumps at https://archive.org/details/stackexchange (not that I have any idea what those looks like inside). Concerning software, see [Are there any clones/alternatives for running a Stack Exchange style Q&A site?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2267) . Importing the Stack Exchange data dumps can’t be that difficult, as witnessed by https://writing.codidact.com (which, however, apparently runs on some sort of temporary software).

Answer (score 5):

Converted from [a comment](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/4431/is-there-a-software-solution-if-we-do-cut-the-cord-from-se/5670#comment21502_4431):

[PhysicsOverflow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PhysicsOverflow) has a setup that's reasonably close to MO. It runs on the [Question2Answer](https://www.question2answer.org/) software. It was in part set up a kind of exodus from physics.stackexchange