# Setting up math Q/A site in foreign language

Tags: discussion, mirror-sites

Now that my college shifted to online education because of the coronavirus, I would like to setup a MathOverflow style site in Hungarian where I could post exercises, and students could comment, post their answers, vote (well, you know, how MathOverflow works), and then see how successful it would be. Apparently, Stackexchange no longer supports non-English sites, and I would require LaTeX support (like on MathOverflow). Does anyone have any suggestion what I could do?

Comment: Talk to the PhysiscOverflow people. I think Dilation is a username associated with that.  Gerhard "They May Still Be Operating" Paseman, 2020.03.14.

Comment: This [meta.se] post might be useful: [Are there any clones/alternatives for running a Stack Exchange style Q&A site?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2267) (It was linked in the comments here: [Is there a software solution if we do cut the cord from SE?](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/4431))

Comment: I'll paste here a relevant question from over there: https://physicsoverflow.org/42605/are-you-willing-share-your-question2answer-configuration and also this:
https://docs.question2answer.org/install/

Comment: Consider also the usage of [Piazza](https://piazza.com/), you can manage your own class without the need of setting up a new site.

Comment: Isn't MO already a math Q/A site in foreign language (for many of us)?